# Медленно качаются FileStream'ы из MS SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

В общем, есть метод, который шлет запрос к БД и выкачивает 2 файла весом ~150мб. Т.е по очереди выкачивается по 1 файлу.

Файлы хранятся в виде стрима.

Проблема в том, что первый файл выкачивается практически моментально, а второй качается со скоростью улитки... Т.е по наблюдения он выкачал 14/150 мб за 5 минут.

Метод скачивания вообще достаточно простой и тривиальный- порциями копировать в массив `byte[4096]` и записывать в файл.

Утилизация сети маленькая.

Может у самого MS SQL стрима, есть какие-то подводные камни?

Ридер открывается так:

```
 using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
```

А дальше читается так:

```
 var buf = new byte[4096];
    long pos = 0;
    using (var fs = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        long readden;
        do
        {
            readden = reader.GetBytes(0, pos, buf, 0, buf.Length);
            fs.Write(buf, 0, (int) readden);
            pos += readden;
        } while (readden != 0);
    }
```

Стрим не используется, так как проект Net Framework 4.0, а стримы завезли в 4,5.

Comment: @i-one добавил.

Comment: @i-one, но у меня фреймворк 4,0...

Comment: Хм. Может просто дисковая подсистема плохо отзывается. Т.е. первый файл мог из дискового кэша зачитаться, и если кэш <150мб, второй станет медленнее отдаваться. Можно попробовать во время скачивания посмотреть ожидания. Есть ли долгие ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION. Помониторить с какой скоростью чтение диска происходит.

Comment: Почитайте [Why is My Database Application so Slow?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-performance/database-application-slow/).